# Get records based on quarter values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have users and expenditures table. Expenditures table has fields called user_id, amount, and entry_date. How can I get old those users whose sum of expenditure in the current quarter is less than sum of expenditure in the previous quarter?

```
users=User.all
users = users.requested_users
```

user.rb
has_many :expenditures

expenditure.rb
belongs_to :user

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is fairly small, you can use ruby to do this.  If it's huge you'll need to do some group_by stuff on your database which will vary depending on which database you're using.

How about something like this (completely untested):

```rb
# user.rb

def self.requested_users
  all.select{ |user| user.expenditures.last_quarter_range.sum(:amount) > user.expenditures.current_quarter_range.sum(:amount) }
end
```

```rb
# expenditure.rb

def self.last_quarter_range
  all.where(entry_date: Date.today.last_quarter.beginning_of_quarter .. Date.today.last_quarter.end_of_quarter)
end

def self.current_quarter_range
  all.where(entry_date: Date.today.beginning_of_quarter .. Date.today.end_of_quarter)
end
```

Comment: The ActiveRecord method to add a GROUP BY clause is actually named `.group`. `#group_by` is a method from Enumerable that groups elements by looping through them and calling a method on each member.